# Is Git concurrency safe on client side?

Tags: git

We had some idea to manage our script through a web page with Git.
There will be only one working directory and single user (apache).
But the apache user will operate on local copy concurrently.
Is Git ok for that? Or we need to serialize all the request?

The system is web based. People on their browser have access to scripts maintained. The backend is an web server with CGI. The CGI calls git client on local copy. 
In the system need to maintain different version of user's scripts.
The interface is likely to be
Create file / Save File (different versions) / Get content by path / Get content of a specific version of file / Delete file

It's likely that most cases users working on their own content but stil chances that two people working on the same file.

Comment: Provide an example of what you are trying to achieve -- your goal is unclear.

Comment: Yeah, an example would be good. Reading the repository would probably be fine, writes almost certainly would not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

I'm not sure of exactly what commands you plan to run, but according to [this video](http://vimeo.com/49444883), rebase does not support concurrency.